# Show Message According to TIme

Tags: android, multithreading, time

I've a TextView where I want to set a message according to time ( hour of day). To achieve this I'm using-

```
Thread t2 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(3600000);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                       int hour=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

                           update(hour);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }


    };
t2.start();
```

where update(hour) is used to update the message.

This works fine, however, the updating is done depending on the launching time. For example, the message should update at time 20:00. But if the app is launched at 19:59, the updating takes place at 20:59.

If I use `Thread.sleep(1000)` it works just as expected. But I feel like wasting resource by running the thread every second just to look for a 1 hour event. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need to check the current time, get the minutes past the hour, then work out from there when the next hour 00 will come. Then, just sleep time for those minutes, then for all the hours after that sleep for the full hour.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

> The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.